# Compare csv files based on column value

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I have two large csv files:

File1.csv

```
id,name,code
1,dummy,0
2,micheal,3
5,abc,4
```

File2.csv

```
id,name,code
2,micheal,4
5,abc,4
1,cd,0
```

I want to compare two files based on id and if any of the columns are mismatched, I want to output those rows.

for example for the id 1 name is different and for id 2 the code is different, the output should be:

output

```
1,cd,0
2,micheal,4
```

and yes both files will have the same ids, could be in different order though.

I want to write a script that can give me above output.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Did you have test my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65608417/757714 ?

Answer (score 3):

If you need what in File2 is not paired with File1, you can use [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and this simple command

```
mlr --csv join --np --ur  -j id,name,code -f File1.csv File2.csv >./out.csv
```

In output you will have

```
+----+---------+------+
| id | name    | code |
+----+---------+------+
| 2  | micheal | 4    |
| 1  | cd      | 0    |
+----+---------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR && FNR!=1 { map[$0]=1;next } FNR!=1 { if ( !map[$0] ) { print } }' File1.csv File2.csv
```

Set the field separator to comma. For the first file (NR==FNR), create an array map with the line as the first index. Then for the second file, if there is no entry for the line in map, print the line.

Answer (score 1):

The tool of choice for finding differences between files is, of course, `diff`. Here, it doesn't really matter if these files are comma-separated or in some other format because you're really only interested in lines that differ.

Knowing that both files contain the same IDs makes this quite easy, although the fact that they will not necessarily be in the same order requires to first `sort` them both.

In your example, you want as output the lines from `File2` so running the `diff` output through a `grep` for `^>` will give you that.

Finally, let's get rid of the two additional characters at the beginning of the output lines that will have been inserted by `diff`, using `cut`:

```sh
diff <(sort File1.csv) <(sort File2.csv) | grep '^>' | cut -c3-
```